# Camel response null even after payload has data after aggregate

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel

```
From("direct:route1")
.streamCaching()
.split(exchangeProperty("splitList",list)
.toD("direct:fetchurl")
.aggregate(constant(true),MyAggregator())
.completionSize(simple("\$exchangeProperty.CamelSplitSize"))
.log("response ${in.body}")
```

I am able to obtain the aggregated data, which I verified through a log statement in the code. However, when I make a request to this route using FluentProducerTemplate.request, the response is null. If I remove the split operation, I can see the response without any issues.
Camel version used is 2.2

I have seen similar posts but nothing worked yet.

Comment: What is your MyAggregator doing ? Camel provides some aggregators that are helpful for usual wanted results. See this article : https://blog.joshdreagan.com/2018/08/30/camel_aggregation_strategies/